# How use parameter in import statement?

Tags: scala, import

I have flowing structure one the package in my project:

```
mypackage/
    package1/
       ...
       package.scala
    package2/
       ...
       package.scala
    package3/
       ...
       package.scala
```

In package1/package.scala:

```
package object package1 {
    val checkMap = Map("a" -> 1)
}
```

In package2/package.scala:

```
package object package2 {
    val checkMap = Map("b" -> 2)
}
```

In package3/package.scala:

```
package object package3 {
    val checkMap = Map("c" -> 3)
}
```

(I have simplified the actual code for the demonstration)

In other place my project I have this stupid code:

```
class CheckThis(packageName: String) {
   var checkerMap = Map[String, Int]()
   if (packageName == "package1"){
       import com.some.some_prj.mypackage.package1.checkMap
       checkerMap = check
   } else if (packageName == "package2"){
       import com.some.some_prj.mypackage.package2.checkMap
       checkerMap = check
   } else if (packageName == "package3"){
       import com.some.some_prj.mypackage.package3.checkMap
       checkerMap = check

   def checker(val: String) = checkerMap.getOrElse(val, -1)

}
```

Now I need to add `package4`, `package5`, `package6` ... into `mypackage`

How use parameter in import statement?

Something like:

```
class CheckThis(packageName: String) {

    import com.some.some_prj.mypackage.$packageName.{checkMap => checkerMap}
```

Or maybe there is a functional variant of import statement:

```
class CheckThis(packageName: String) {

    val checkerMap:Map[String, Int] = import(s"com.some.some_prj.mypackage.$packageName.checkMap"}
```

Comment: Why do you **specifically** want to solve your problem like that? What's wrong with e.g. using a Map[String,Map[String,Int]] in your case?

Comment: Code in `package.scala` files much more difficult than I wrote in the question. `(I have simplified the actual code for the demonstration)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, not without resorting to macros or manipulating classloading, either of which would probably be an overkill for whatever you're doing**.

Here's the full subgrammar for import statements from Chapter 4.7 of [the SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

```
Import ::=           ‘ import ’ ImportExpr {‘,’ ImportExpr}
ImportExpr ::=       StableId ‘.’ (id | ‘_’ | ImportSelectors)
ImportSelectors ::=  ‘{’ {ImportSelector ‘,’}
                        (ImportSelector | ‘_’) ‘}’
ImportSelector ::=   id [‘=>’ id | ‘=>’ ‘_’]
```

As you can see there is not way to insert something parametrized there. You have to either stick to your original boilerplate-based approach, or use an alternative (the choice of which depending on how your "checker" code structure actually looks like).

Comment: My intuition and previous experience tells me you're "importing" a structural design pattern from other languages - most probably Python. I suggest reading up on various design patterns idiomatic to Scala instead.

Comment: You're right) I mostly write the code on Python. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Scala it is not possible to generate import statements at runtime, all imports are resolved at compile time. For such an usecase it is easy to use a Map that contains a value to determine the code that should be executed (or even the code itself in form of a function):

```
// R is the return value
val m = Map[String, () => R] = {
  val block1 = { () =>
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
    ret
  }
  val block2 = { () =>
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
    ret2
  }
  Map("package1" -> block1, "package2" -> block2)
}

val f = m(packageName)
// execute code here and use return value if necessarey
val ret = f()
```